# How do we can create the attractive/customised installer for our .net application?

Tags: c#

I am usually using Setup and Deployment template provided by visual studio. Is it possible to enhance default forms provided in that. or is there anything else to create the customized and attractive installer.

Aim : 
1. I like to ask the user for pre-requested information to initialize the application during the installation process.
2. I like to prevent app.config by toching from user.
3. I like verify the collect the connection information during installation as well as like to verify that by connecting with given data source.

please provide good direction if i am in wrong path. - thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Wix](http://wix.sourceforge.net/) is what you need

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do all these things with the built in setup project in Visual Studio.

1. You can add a new user interface dialog box with text boxes, check boxes etc.
   Write a custom action the handles these values and store them in some configuration file.
2. The app.config shouldn't be touched by the user anyway. If you are using the built in configuration classes in .NET, the user settings will be stored in a separated file in the user's application data folders.
3. As in #1, you can use custom actions for this kind of functionality.

The built in setup project has very little/no means of customizing the look and feel. For that you will have to use either 3rd party components/installers or use WiX and design setup screens/dialogs by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I use Inno Setup (http://www.innosetup.com/isinfo.php), its free and very configurable, it can also run your own applications as helpers to do very specific tasks.

Answer (score 0):

Why not try other install systems like InstallShield or, if you really want to customize go for NSIS (Nullsoft Scriptable Install System)? [NSIS Download](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Download)